# Parse output with dynamic col widths and empty fields

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, google-drive

[gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) has a sub command `list` which prints a list of files like the following example:

```
gdrive list
```

Output:

```
Id                                  Name                      Type   Size     Created
1sV3_a1ySV0-jbLxhA8NIEts1KU_aWa-5   info.pdf                  bin    10.0 B   2018-08-27 20:26:20
1h-j3B5OLryp6HkeyTsd9PJaAtKK_GYyl   2018-12-ss-scalettapass   dir             2018-08-27 20:26:19
```

I'm trying to parse this output using tools like `awk` and `sed` without success.

The problems are empty 'fields' in the size column and the dynamic widths of the columns.

Has anybody an idea how to parse this output?

Comment: it [appears to me](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive/blob/master/drive/list.go) that the columns are tab-delimited; can you confirm with `gdrive list | sed -n l`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: I also looked at this code. These tabs are somehow converted to spaces. Besides `gdrive list | sed -n l` I also tried `gdrive list | cat -A`, which did not make any special characters visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk can deal with fixed width data. First we need to determine the column widths:

```
fieldwidths=$(head -n 1 file | grep -Po '\S+\s*' | awk '{printf "%d ", length($0)}')
```

This value is `"36 26 7 9 7 "` -- the last field is larger than 7 chars. Let's arbitrarily make it 70 chars:

```
fieldwidths=${fieldwidths/% /0}
```

Now, let's read the data and turn it into CSV:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="$fieldwidths" '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        val = $i
        sub(/ *$/, "", val)
        gsub(/"/, "\"\"", val)
        printf "%s\"%s\"", (i==1 ? "" : ","), val
    }
    print ""
}' file
```

outputs:

```
"Id","Name","Type","Size","Created"
"1sV3_a1ySV0-jbLxhA8NIEts1KU_aWa-5","info.pdf","bin","10.0 B","2018-08-27 20:26:20"
"1h-j3B5OLryp6HkeyTsd9PJaAtKK_GYyl","2018-12-ss-scalettapass","dir","","2018-08-27 20:26:19"
```

---

The same functionality with perl

```
perl -lne '
    if ($. == 1) {
        @head = ( /(\S+\s*)/g );
        pop @head;
        $patt = "^";
        $patt .= "(.{" . length($_) . "})" for @head;
        $patt .= "(.*)\$";
    }
    print join ",", map {s/"/""/g; s/\s+$//; qq("$_")} (/$patt/o);
' file
```

Comment: Not all `awk` versions offer the FIELDWIDTHS option.

Comment: @glenn-jackman: Thank you for your answers. Finally, I chose your Perl-based solution that was most understandable to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `Perl` using the `unpack` function by creating the unpacking template dynamically by examining the header (1st line):

```
perl -lpe '
    $fmt //= join "", map("A" . length(), /\H+\h+(?=\H)/g), "A*";
    $_ = join ",", map { s/"/""/gr =~ s/(.*)/"$1"/r } unpack $fmt;
' input-file.txt
```

**Explanation:**

- `-p` will make `perl` consume the file on a per-line basis. Each line, aka, record, is referred to as `$_`. Another effect of `-p` is it autoprints the current record before going to fetch the next one.
- `-l` does 2 things, sets `ORS = RS = \n`
- The regex `/\H+\h+(?=\H)/g` shall fetch all the fields except the last and then these are fed to `map`.
- `map` computes the lengths of these fields and prefixes an "A" to each.
- In lieu of not selecting the last field above, we add a catch-all "A*".
- These then are passed to `join` which sticks them together into a string using the null delimiter. So the unpack format is ready for use and is not computed again because of the `//=` operator which is the `defined-or` function.
- Now, armed with the dynamically created unpack format, we proceed to apply to every line, including the header.
- `unpack` unpacks a string, in our case the current line, using the format provided and emits fields unpacked.
- These emitted fields are then input to `map` which operates on each one-by-one, and performs the steps outlined in the `{ ... }` code. In our case, in each field we do the following: a) double the double quotes. b) enrobe the field with double quotes.
- After `map` is done editing the fields, it throws them over to `join`, which joins them using the comma `,` to form a nice little `CSV` file.
- **P.S.:** Notice that we didn't have to trim the trailing blanks in the fields generated by `unpack`, coz, `unpack` does that for you when using the `A` (A for ASCII) formatting character.

**Output:**

```
"Id","Name","Type","Size","Created"
"1sV3_a1ySV0-jbLxhA8NIEts1KU_aWa-5","info.pdf","bin","10.0 B","2018-08-27 20:26:20"
"1h-j3B5OLryp6HkeyTsd9PJaAtKK_GYyl","2018-12-ss-scalettapass","dir","","2018-08-27 20:26:19"
```

---

This can be done by the `sed` tool, but would need a two-pass approach, in that first, using the header line of the input, we generate a `sed` script dynamically, which then operates upon the input file (including the header as well) to perform the desired operation, as shown:

```
if="input-file.txt"
cmd=$(< "$if" head -n 1 | perl -lne 'print join $/, reverse map { $s += length();qq[s/./\\n/$s] } /\H+\h+(?=\H)/g')
sed -e '
    '"${cmd}"'
    s/"/""/g
    s/[[:blank:]]*\n/","/g
    s/.*/"&"/
' < "$if"
```

Comment: Just a heads-up, Rakesh -- you appear to have two unregistered accounts, [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/287967/rakesh-sharma) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/290591/rakesh-sharma)

Comment: so this works with ASCII only and not Unicode?